# Error in junit while mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I am new to Junit,Below is the junit code which i am running.

```
package com.de.base.util.general;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JReportUtilTest {
@InjectMocks 
ReportUtil w_res = new ReportUtil();

@Mock
CollectionUtil w_util;

@Test
public void test_removeHashedSettings() throws Exception {
    HashMap<String ,String> w_abc = new HashMap<String,String>();
    w_abc.put("abc","89");
    //CollectionUtil mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(CollectionUtil.class);
    //PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class,w_abc);          
    when(w_util.createHashMap("abc:89", ":")).thenReturn(w_abc);
    assertEquals("abc:89:",ReportUtil.removeHashedSettings("1", "abc:89", ":"));
}
}
```

Here is my api removedHashedSettingsin ReportUtil

```
public static String removeHashedSettings(String key, String a_settings, String deilimiter) throws Exception
    {
        if (!(key != null && key.trim().length() > 0))
            return a_settings;
        if (!(a_settings != null && a_settings.trim().length() > 0))
            return a_settings;

        HashMap hSettings = CollectionUtil.createHashMap(a_settings, deilimiter);
        hSettings.remove(key);
        return getSettingFromHash(hSettings, deilimiter);
    }
```

Below is the code for createHashMap in CollectionUtil which i have to mock.

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createHashMap(String a_NameValStr, String a_Delim)// throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, String> w_KeyVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) LOGGER.info("CollectionUtil:createHashMap:Hashing string: "+ a_NameValStr );

        if(a_NameValStr == null) return w_KeyVal;

            StringTokenizer w_StrTkn = new StringTokenizer(a_NameValStr, a_Delim);
            if( w_StrTkn.countTokens() == 0 || (w_StrTkn.countTokens()%2) != 0 )
            {
                LOGGER.warn("CollectionUtil:createHashMap:Invalid number of tokens to hash: "+ a_NameValStr+":"+w_StrTkn.countTokens() );
                return w_KeyVal;
            }

            while (w_StrTkn.hasMoreTokens()) w_KeyVal.put( w_StrTkn.nextToken(), w_StrTkn.nextToken());
        System.out.println(w_KeyVal);   
        return w_KeyVal;
    }
```

Here is the error i am getting while running my junit test case.

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at com.de.base.util.general.JReportUtilTest.test_removeHashedSettings(JReportUtilTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I am using mockito -all-1.10.19.jar,powermock-api-mockito-1.6.6.jar,powermock-core-1.6.6.jar,powermock-module-junit4-1.6.6.jar
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: is CollectionUtil a final class?

Comment: it is not a final class

Comment: The methods you are trying to mock in  `CollectionUtil` are static therefore you need `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(CollectionUtil.class)` on class. Furthermore you need then to call `PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CollectionUtil.class)
public class TestHarnesTest {
    @InjectMocks
    TestHarnes w_res = new TestHarnes();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_removeHashedSettings() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> w_abc = new HashMap<String, String>();
        w_abc.put("abc", "89");
        // CollectionUtil mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(CollectionUtil.class);
        // PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class,w_abc);
        PowerMockito.when(CollectionUtil.createHashMap(Mockito.eq("abc:89"), Mockito.eq(":"))).thenReturn(w_abc);
        assertEquals("abc:89:", TestHarnes.removeHashedSettings("1", "abc:89", ":"));
    }
}
```

and the TestHarnes class

```
public class TestHarnes {

    public static String removeHashedSettings(final String key, final String a_settings, final String deilimiter) throws Exception {
        if (!(key != null && key.trim().length() > 0)) {
            return a_settings;
        }
        if (!(a_settings != null && a_settings.trim().length() > 0)) {
            return a_settings;
        }

        HashMap hSettings = CollectionUtil.createHashMap(a_settings, deilimiter);
        hSettings.remove(key);
        return getSettingFromHash(hSettings, deilimiter);
    }

    private static String getSettingFromHash(final HashMap hSettings, final String deilimiter) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting error in  PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class);

Comment: error is :- The type org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: What is yor CollectionUtil class? from which Framework is it?

Comment: Thank you for your help.But when i run your code.Following error has been generated.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments

Comment: add powermock-api-mockito-common-1.6.6.jar to your dependency

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the PowerMock runner :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

Mockito cannot mock static method but PowerMock does.

And you should mock the class with static method :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(CollectionUtil.class);
```

Anyway a better design is replacing the static method by an instance method.
Static methods are not naturally testable and force to create complex and not readable workaround.
For example, look at the complexity of the mix of dependencies required to test a simple class.

You should keep the **use of static methods as helper that don't perform core logic of the domain and that don't need to be mocked**.
When the methods perform core logic of the domain as it is the case for the `createHashMap() static method`, you very probably need to mock it to not create side effects between dependent classes during the tests. 
And as you have noticed : mocking static methods is really clumsy as static methods are really not designed to be overriden.

Besides, for core logic of the domain, you should have the ability to take advantage of the OOP (inheritancy, polymorphism, design patterns, etc... ), how to achieve it with static methods ? –

For legacy code we cannot really not change, it is acceptable but otherwise, no it doesn't and you should refactor your code.

Comment: I am using 3 powermock jars as mentioned above.But i am still getting this error while implementing your code.

Comment: The type org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: Either you miss a dependency or your IDE is not refreshed. When I say that i force to create complex workaround : look at the complexity of the mix dependency required to test a simple class.

Comment: For a utility class with no state, why isn't it good design to use static methods?
It saves the creation of an object, resulting in a shorter, cleaner, production code.

Comment: @Yoav Gur I agree when static method is an helper that doesn't perform  core logic of your domain and so you don't need to mock it. When it perform core logic of your domain as here, you may need to mock it to not create side effects between dependent classes during the tests. And  a static method that you mock is not a shorter cleaner code. Besides, for core logic of your domain, you should have the ability to take advantage of the OOP (inheritancy, polymorphism, design patterns, etc... ), how to achieve it with static methods ?

Comment: @davidxxx Good answer. I tend to agree.

Comment: @Yoav GurI I would have explained it in my original answer. I have just improved the answer with these details.